# Will dried ginger piece be more potent than dried ground ginger of same age and storage?

Tags: ginger, aroma

If you get 2 sets of black peppercorns, leave one set whole and ground the other then leave them both out over time the ground version will loose potency and aroma due to being exposed to air.  When one uses/grinds the whole set at the point of use the potency will be far superior.

I want to know if dried ginger unground and dried ginger ground and left out for the same amount of time will have the same level of superiority? In another answer I believe I read that dehydrated ginger(even if not ground) will loose potency over time but this doesn’t really happen to whole black peppercorns.

If then the dehydrated unground ginger does loose potency over time will it still be significantly superior to ground ginger or will it be quite bland/just a little superior so there’s no point not grounding it earlier if you are doing so to try and preserve potency.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me, that you are asking basically the same questions over and over again. Not just here, but also on mechanics.se

Comment: @how would such a question be accepted on mechanics.se? my last question was asking about preservation and one of the answers said surface area is an issue but it wasn’t clear to me if air still get into a dried whole piece or not.

Comment: This & all the other recent ginger questions, are basically a rehash of last year's curry & chilli questions, just with the word 'ginger' substituted. Can you not extrapolate from the answers to your earlier questions as to how the same principles apply also to ginger [or any spice]?

Comment: @Tetsujin what I am confused about is that the whole dried ginger piece is a ginger which is dehydrated and maybe a bit cut off.  This is different from a while black peppercorn which is not dehydrated or cracked open.  Im Not sure if air gets inside the dehydrated ginger significantly more then dehydrated ginger which has been ground hence the question.

Comment: …so the answer to my question "Can you not extrapolate..?" would appear to be, "No."

Comment: @Tetsujin I did extrapolate which is why I explained my understanding which was based those answers - that dried unground pieces are exposed to less air than ground so will be potent for long.  However I also explained that I didn’t think a dried piece surface was air tight so the inside would still be exposed to air and hence wondering/asking if the lasting potency would be significantly different between the two.

Comment: After your edit - your premise is incorrect. Peppercorns left in the open air will of course lose their more volatile compounds… as will anything left in the open air. Surface area to volume ratio will play an important part. This has all been covered before.

Comment: the simplest answer I can provide would be yes,

Answer (score 2):

Ground spices will turn bad (go stale, loose potency) faster than their unground (whole) state.

This is because ground spices have a lot more surface to air ratio and will oxidize quicker; oxygen is the culprit.

This is the case for ginger as well as any other spices.

This is why most people will keep spices whole and grind/crush them at the last minute.

If you want to keep ground spices for a long time, you need to keep them in an air free environment, vacuum seal pack will help, but each it you want to use some, you will need to open the package and vacuum seal it again.

Comment: I edited, the culprit is not air, it's oxygen.

Comment: "Most" people might be an overstatement. :) I'm the only person I know who routinely fresh grinds any spice other than pepper. (In my experience, only the Indian grocer has a large selection of whole spices on hand.)